# html2canvas doesn't always generate the image correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm getting crazy about this very odd error with html2canvas.
I use this library all the time and I've never had a problem like that, but now, I don't know for what weird reason, sometimes ( I would say 3 times out of 5 ) it retrieves a blank picture.

Here is my code:

```
<div class = "textResult"><?php echo $variable; ?></div>
```

js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var element = $(".textResult")[0];
            html2canvas(element,{allowTaint: true,logging: true,taintTest: false}).then(function(canvas) {
                    wmContext   =   canvas.getContext("2d");
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'urltosend.php',
                        data: {
                          // send image string as data
                          imgStr: dataURL,
                          imgName: "picture.png"
                        },
                    });
            });  
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Can PLEASE someone explain me what is wrong with that?

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console log?

Comment: Believe it or not but the error got resolved by itself. The day after, without doing nothing it worked! I'm programming for more then 10 years and I've never had a situation like that

Comment: If you figure out what happened, please come back and post the answer. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Of course I will :)